# Why the layout of Android app widgets is based on RemoteViews?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

As subjected. Instead of RemoteViews, why can't the layout of app widget be based on real layout?

Is it because the process to update the real layout of app widget and the process in which AppWidgetProvider is running are different?

Answer (score 0):

Appwidgets themselves run on in the Home Screen and are not part of your app and its process. Directly accessing it would mean access to the rest of the system, and that would be a bad thing security wise. Thats why AppWidgets use RemoteViews instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's inline with what I thought of.